# create parametric scripted_metric in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I want to use scripted_metric within an aggregation. I have some parametric values in my script that I want to set those per query, It is possible to create this query at all? 
below an example for what I'm looking for

```
"aggs": {
    "testAgg": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "_agg['maximum'] = []",
        "map_script": "max = 0; for(tv in _source.tvs){ if(tv.att1>= param1 && tv.attr2 <= param2 && tv.att3 > max){max = tv.att3; }}; _agg.maximum.add(max);",
        "combine_script": "sum = 0; for (m in _agg.maximum) { sum += m }; return sum;",
        "reduce_script": "sum = 0; for (a in _aggs) { sum += a }; return sum;"
      }
    }
  }
```

param1 and param2 are my parametric values, how to change this aggregation for my purpose?

tnx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by specifying a global `params` map

```
"aggs": {
    "testAgg": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "params": {
           "_agg": {},
           "param1": 10,
           "param2": 20
        },
        "init_script": "_agg['maximum'] = []",
        "map_script": "max = 0; for(tv in _source.tvs){ if(tv.att1>= param1 && tv.attr2 <= param2 && tv.att3 > max){max = tv.att3; }}; _agg.maximum.add(max);",
        "combine_script": "sum = 0; for (m in _agg.maximum) { sum += m }; return sum;",
        "reduce_script": "sum = 0; for (a in _aggs) { sum += a }; return sum;"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I try this myself, but when add "params" attribute, and run the query I got this error: "reason": {
                    "type": "script_exception",
                    "reason": "failed to run inline script [_agg['maximum'] = []] using lang [groovy]",
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "missing_property_exception",
                        "reason": "No such property: _agg for class: 61d7231114f6331ff30ad062a76adc50bd85e778"
                    }
                }

Comment: without "params" attribute it's work fine and correctly

Comment: Which version of ES do you have? Have you [enabled dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in aggregations?

Comment: its version is 2.3.4, and I just enable these:
`script.engine.groovy.inline.update: on`
`script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on`
`script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on`

Comment: a add 
`script.inline: true
script.indexed: true`
to my `elasticsearch.yml` and restart my node, but the error still exists

Comment: interesting... let me think about it

Comment: are you find any solution?!

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you provide a `params` section, you need to actually redefine the `_agg` parameter, like above. Works now.

Comment: I've filed an issue as this behavior is not intuitive: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/19768 We'll see what happens.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that

Comment: So I think I deserve to get an upvote for my question :D